# Custom word breakers in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We're implementing a tagging system for our site, where tags are delimited by a comma (",") and using fulltext-search in sql server to search for items tagged with something. The problem is, whe're finding the search results a bit too forgiving and would like searches to **only** break on commas.

We found an article on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207002.aspx) describing how to install custom word breakers, but we're not to keen on paying a third party to deliver a .dll to us - is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You mean except implementing the DLL yourself? No. But that is something you can do. Just start programming ;)

Note taht this is 208 R2 (!) only as a solution, so it is not even applciable to your database server (which you say is 2008).

Comment: Here's the SQL 2008 version at that article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207002%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx  Customer word breakers are fully supported on SQL 2008 as well.  There isn't much change in full text search (if any) between SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to write a custom word breaker dll and attach that to the SQL Server.  Also here's the [SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207002%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) version of that article (unless you are actually on R2).

Comment: How would this compare to writing a replacement set in the sql server thesaurus replacing all delimiters with nothing? I.E:
<replacement>
         <pat>-</pat>
         <sub></sub>
</replacement>

Comment: A custom word breaker would be more efficient over all, as string replacement in SQL Server is not efficient in the slightest.